# Is python3.6 new change 'async for' not compatible with enumerate

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am trying to move my apps from python2.7 to python3.6,for the asyncio and relates libs,but I find some functions are not working as I excepted.
I use motor to query from mongodb asyncly,like:

```
async def do_query():
    song_already_processed = set()
    song_table = db.song_table
    async for index, item in enumerate(song_table.find({'lang': 'English'},
                              {'id': 1, '_id': 0, 'title': 1, 'artist.name': 1})):
        if index > 100:
            break
        if item['id'] in song_already_processed:
            continue
        song_already_processed.add(item['id'])

    print(len(song_already_processed))
```

but it raised the error:

```
TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not iterable
```

I think the async iterator protocol is diffirent from normal interator protocol,so the enumerate didn't work well.Is there is an async enumerate I can use?

By the way, I know a lot of ways to just get 100 doc and stop the iterate, I just want to know how to use 'async for' properly

Comment: `song_table.find` just returns a cursor object, why do you think it can be iterated?

Comment: @Sraw TBF, a cursor seems as "something iterable". Of course seeming and..

Comment: An asynchronous iterator and an iterator are two different things, and tools built around the functionality of one probably won't work on the other.  As far as I know there isn't an official implementation for `aenumerate` yet, but you can look at [this](https://pythonwise.blogspot.com/2015/11/aenumerate-enumerate-for-async-for.html) to see how one would be structured

Answer (score 19):

The [`asyncstdlib` library](https://pypi.org/project/asyncstdlib/) (disclaimer: I maintain this package) provides `async` variants of standard library helpers. In specific, [`asyncstdlib.enumerate`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/builtins.html#asyncstdlib.builtins.enumerate) works like `enumerate` but takes and produces an async iterable.

```
import asyncstdlib as a

async for index, item in a.enumerate(song_table.find(...)):
    if index > 100:
        break
    ...
```

Note that it is generally not a good idea to `break` out of an async iteration -- the iterator may not cleanup at the end of iteration (see [PEP 533 for details](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0533/)).

Since you are using `index` just to get the first 100 items, you can also use [`asyncstdlib.islice`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/itertools.html#asyncstdlib.itertools.islice) to safely limit the iteration directly:

```
import asyncstdlib as a

async for item in a.islice(song_table.find(...), 100):
    ...
```

---

Python3.6 added [asynchronous generators](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep525), which allows to easily implement async enumeration:

```
async def aenumerate(asequence, start=0):
    """Asynchronously enumerate an async iterator from a given start value"""
    n = start
    async for elem in asequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

For older versions of Python, one must reify the async generator by hand:

```
class AsyncEnumerate:
    """Asynchronously enumerate an async iterator from a given start value"""
    def __init__(self, asequence, start=0):
        self._asequence = asequence
        self._value = start

    async def __anext__(self):
        elem = await self._asequence.__anext__()
        value, self._value = self._value, self._value + 1
        return value, elem

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind having an external dependency, you can use [aiostream.stream.enumerate](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.enumerate):

```
async for i, item in aiostream.stream.enumerate(cursor):
    ...
```

See more examples in this [demonstration](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream#demonstration) and the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'aiostream' has no attribute 'enumerate'`

Comment: `aiostream.enumerate` => `aiostream.stream.enumerate` FTFY

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar question that involved using an asynchronous generator as an iterable using an enumerate and an async for. I realized the simplest answer in my situation was to actually return an index via modification of the **async generator** to return the index, and not the **async for**. see below:

```py
async def whitespace(data: List) -> tuple:
    """function to remove any whitespace in returned values"""
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        yield i, x.strip()

async for i, x in whitespace(a_list_of_stuff):
    a_list_of_stuff[i] = x
```